# p5.Vector.prototype.mult: x, y, or z arguments are either undefined or not a finite number

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
    updateVelocity(allBodies, timeStep){
        for (let otherBody of allBodies) {



            if(otherBody != this){                
                let sqrDst = (p5.Vector.sub(otherBody.pos, this.pos).mag());
                let forceDir = (p5.Vector.sub(otherBody.pos, this.pos).normalize());
                let force = p5.Vector.mult(forceDir, gravity * this.mass * otherBody.mass / sqrDst);
                let acceleration = p5.Vector.div(force, this.mass);
                this.currentVelocity.add(acceleration * timeStep);
            }
        }
    }


    updatePosition(timeStep){
        this.pos.add(this.currentVelocity * timeStep);
        ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius);
    }
}
```

I am trying to replicate Sebastian Lague's solar system video but with p5.js

I am getting this error **p5.Vector.prototype.mult: x, y, or z arguments are either undefined or not a finite number**. When I remove the line where i multiply it disapears but that makes the whole thing not work. I looked it up and it could be that the z value is automatically 0, but i tried setting it manually to 1 by adding and it still didnt work.

I did some debugging and found out that the force actually changes but as the planets dont move it stays the same after a while and nothing happens.

How do i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Console log `forceDir`. I suspect one of the vector components is infinity (or undefined).

Comment: The z component was 0 but setting it to 1 didnt change anything. Still got the error

Comment: This error message refers not to the components of the `p5.Vector` but to the arguments other arguments that are passed to the `mult()` function (the static version of this function `p5.Vector.mult(v, f)` is equivalent to `v.copy().mult(f)`). So my guess would be that some component of this equation is either undefined, NaN, Infinity, or not a number: `gravity * this.mass * otherBody.mass / sqrDst` or `sqrDst` is 0.